# C++: Play .Wav file that is in the same folder?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, gnu

I'm just wondering if there is a way to play a .wav file in C++ Console App (GNU GCC Compiler)?

If the answer is yes then please provide some tips, a snippet, or anything else that you think may help me understand how to do this.

The .wav file is going to be in the same folder as the .exe :)

Comment: This depends less on the compiler than the OS.

Comment: -1 for not providing details on the environment when asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlaySound function (mmsystem.h) is really the simplest way how to play a wav file in a win console application. Libsndfile library is probably the most powerful free audio file library available (support for tens of audio file formats including ogg and flac), but you read raw audio data - samples, so to be able to play them, you must send them to the audio device, which is not so simple...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use windows.h, there's a function that works like this:

```
PlaySound("C:\\SOUNDS\\BELLS.WAV", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, people have said that [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) is a simple way to handle WAV files.